# Timer that closes modal form in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have several modeless Forms with grids to show data in a MDI Windows Forms app (`Form1` in example code). Each of these Forms has a button that opens another Form as modal using `ShowDialog` (`Form2` in example code), which allows editing the data shown in `Form1`. These modal forms have a Cancel button that closes the form without saving changes by setting `DialogResult` to `Cancel`.

I want to implement a timer that closes all forms after a certain time has elapsed from user login into the app. The problem arises if the timer triggers while a modal Form is open.

```
public partial class Form1 : 
{ //Constructor ommited for brevity
    private void btnEditData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var form2 = new Form2();
        timer1.Tick += (_, __) =>
        {
            form2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
            this.Close(); // this executes before form2.ShowDialog returns
        };
        timer1.Interval = 5_000;
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        form2.ShowDialog();
        reloadData(); // here Form1 is already disposed because Close 
        // has been called on it. An exception is thrown as a consequence
    }

    private void reloadData()
    {
        if (this.IsDisposed)
            // simulate using a disposed form
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.Name); 
    }
}
```

My intention would be to somehow schedule the call `Form1.Close()` after `form2.ShowDialog()` has returned and the `btnEditData_Click` method has finished, so that there would be no danger of using a disposed form.

Comment: perhaps you can post some code, to help people provide a solution?

Comment: posted some code as per @francesco-b suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**
After seeing your code, I'd suggest to introduce a third option in your Tick event handler that would be used to decide if you have to close the form. For example, `Abort`.

```
 timer1.Tick += (_, __) =>
    {
        form2.DialogResult = DialogResult.Abort;
    };
if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Abort) Close();    
else reloadData();
```

---

First thought: keep it simple and keep it clean. You don't have to keep track of your open forms, in an MDI application there is `MdiChildren` property of the parent form that will give you all the forms. 
Then, to handle the closing part, you can use existing functionalities in .Net.

1. A difficult approach is using [P/Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/55d3thsc.aspx). You load Windows DLLs and use their functions to enumerate through all your forms and close which one you want. You can also simulate a click on Cancel button. You have to start with [EnumWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) function (to identify the forms) and [EnumChildWindows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) for form's children. I like this option because you have full control of your forms and controls, but can give you headaches if not familiar with the concept.
2. You can have a look at FormClosing event and subscribe to it. This event fires before the form is closed and you can make the clean up using it.
3. Using OOP - inheritance and override. Either you create a base form with custom close function that does the cleaning (and then inherit all your forms through it), or override form's close functions to achieve your goal.